# Format text from resourceDictionary in xaml

Tags: xaml, formatting, resourcedictionary

I have a text in my resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<system:String x:Key="ResourceDictionaryName" Localization.Comments="$Content(DoNotLocalize)">Loc-en-EN</system:String>

<!--MainControl.xaml-->   
<system:String x:Key="PersonalEmail">Please enter your email./system:String></ResourceDictionary>
```

and I bind it to xaml this way:

```
   <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource PersonalEmail}" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
```

Is it possible to create style or converter, to show, for example, **Please** bold, and rest of the text as normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String itself does not support rich text format, you can use a [Span](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.span(v=vs.110).aspx) to show the text.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Span>
        <Bold>Please</Bold> enter your email.
    </Span>
</TextBlock>
```

And you can put almost anything into a `ResourceDictionary` and give it a key, and reference it using that key.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Span x:Key="PersonalEmail">
        <Bold>Please</Bold> enter your email.
    </Span>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock>            
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PersonalEmail" />
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. But I would like to know, if there is a way for dynamicResource

Comment: Sorry, seems it has to be `StaticResource` if using `InlineCollections`. `DynamicResource`requires the property being a `DependencyProperty`.