# How to display circled Latin capital letter L as Superscript

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a requirement to show circled Latin capital letter "L" (unicode U+24C1) as superscript to another word in a WPF application. The display text should something like [image].
When I added this in my resource file (typed this letter in Word by using cntl+9409 and copy-pasted to resource file) and displayed on a textbox/block, it has been displayed as normal text (without superscript) - "Welcome... Ⓛ".
Is there any way to display this particular symbol (circled Latin capital letter "L") one level above the other text in WPF/C#?.

Comment: `Ⓛ` is a "normal" character. To display it as a superscript you need to use a Span or Run with `BaselineAlignment="Top"`. You can use Spans as resources instead of just text as the anser to [Format text from resourceDictionary in xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198667/format-text-from-resourcedictionary-in-xaml) shows